# Pigeonhole Principle problem regarding a set of numbers and two subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I have a question for one of my CSI classes and I've never been taught the material before so I'm completely stuck.  The problem asks to take a set of 12 positive integers (not necessarily distinct) from 1-150 and prove that there are two different subsets of 6 integers such that the sums are equal.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hints.

A. In how many ways can you pick 6 number out of 12?

B. The sum of 6 numbers from the set $\{1,2,\ldots,150\}$, how big can be?